# How to use future functions properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `stremBuilder` that get snapshots from firebase, the snapshot contain some post information, and i use this to create a new instance of `Posting` class, and pass this posting to `postingPage`.

one of the properties of `Posting` class is the id of the user who uploaded the post.

I've a function that fetch the user based on id, but I dont know where to call it because it's a `Future` function.

Where do I need to call this fetch user function to get all user data in the `postingPage`?

Preview of the code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _stream,
  builder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshots
  ) {
    if (snapshots.hasError) {
      print(snapshots.error.toString());
    }
    switch (snapshots.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      default:
        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 3 / 4
          ),
          itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
              snapshots.data.documents[index];
            Posting currentPosting =
              posting.getPostingData(snapshot);
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                // Navigator.of(context)
                //     .pushNamed(ViewPostingScrenn.routeName);
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ViewPostingScrenn(
                      posting: currentPosting,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: PostingGridTile()
            );
          },
        );
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: [asyncMap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the futures for your network fetches and use `FutureBuilder` instead of `StreamBuilder` in your widget.